# Term for 'the thing as seen right now'

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there an english word fitting the longer description *'the visible part of something as seen right now'* or *'the thing as it can be understood as of this time'*?

The word *'Impression'* seems to cover this somewhat, but it has the added baggage of being someones opinion, rather than describing the factual state something has, as well as having a different meaning of being a physical depression of an object on another object.

Is there an alternative?

Comment: In what context are you planning to use that word. In computing it might be a [snapshot](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/snapshot).

Comment: Perhaps you're thinking of the psychological term of **imprinting**:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imprinting_(psychology)

Comment: Your first sentence seems to ask for a noun representing the visible portion, but your example *impression* seems to refer to something related to the viewer. Perhaps you're not after a noun at all. Please edit your question with a sample sentence containing a placeholder for the word you're seeking. (E.g. "The leaf was partly obscured; only the stem was ___." Then someone might suggest the word *showing*.)

Comment: I am going with 'Snapshot' as it fit my personal use-case the best, but all answers here are great answers. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Present iteration" might work, particularly if this is a creative work that is known to progress and change.

Otherwise "snapshot" conveys everything you asked, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Like something's first impression?

You probably won't find a word better than impression but maybe "image" or if you're implying it's not what seems, then "facade"?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're looking for "glimpse," meaning "[a momentary or partial view](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20glimpse&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft:en-US:IE-Address&ie=&oe=)."

Answer (score 1):

If it's a physical description, that is less open to interpretation as you say, possibly "current incarnation".